# GoDaddy -> Google Apps for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm an IT specialist for a small company in Indianapolis, and we want to switch our email, calendar, and cloud storage (though not hosting or DNS registration YET - one step at a time) to Google Apps for Business.

The question is, how?  We're a company in full stride, and can't take three weeks off to transfer all the services.  How do I/is there a way to simply transfer the email at least from GoDaddy to Google Apps?  Is there a way to make sure incoming emails never touch GoDaddy's glacial servers (that's what I'd most like to make sure of)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set MX records on your server to do that.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33353&topic=1611273&ctx=topic

Comment: Excellent, that is about ten times easier than I was afraid it would be.  Thank you!